# What is the correct way to detect a device with a vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to be able to detect whether my page is being viewed on a mobile device.

```
grid.addItemClickListener( event -> {        
        if( isMobileView( ) )
        {
            splitLayout.setSplitterPosition( 0 ); 
            backArrow.setVisible( true );
        }
    } );
```

I am using Vaadin Flow 24 as far as it goes and have tried the following. In my opinion it should be easy to use vaadinUtil to detect if the page is being viewed on a mobile device.
Thanks in advance to those who can answer and share their knowledge. I would also like to here from Vaadin official guys.

```
    private boolean isMobileView()
{
    UI ui = UI.getCurrent( );
    Page page = ui.getPage( );
    if( page != null )
    {
        page.retrieveExtendedClientDetails( details -> {
            int screenWidth = details.getScreenWidth( );
            int screenHeight = details.getScreenHeight( );
            isScreenWidthLessThan600 = screenWidth < 600;
        } );
    }
    return isScreenWidthLessThan600;
}

public  boolean isMobileDevice() {
    WebBrowser webBrowser = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getBrowser();
    return webBrowser.isAndroid() || webBrowser.isIPhone() || webBrowser.isWindowsPhone();
}

public  boolean isMobi() {
    String userAgent = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest( ).getHeader( "User-Agent" );
    boolean isMobi = userAgent != null && userAgent.toLowerCase( ).contains( "mobi" );
    
    return isMobi;
}
```

Comment: What is a mobile device? I think you need to first define why you need the distinction. Usually there are two things which might change in the user experience: Screen size and touch input. Is a 10" iPad a mobile device, is a 10" screensized windows pc also a mobile device?

Comment: And the code you are using does not work?  Or are you asking, if there
is an better/official way?

Comment: By mobile I means it should be small screen size and also toush such as Android phone or Iphone.
This code works, I'm asking, if there is an better/official way.